# Composing environment variables with other environment variables in k8s containers

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

Can environment variables passed to containers be composed from environment variables that already exist? Something like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: URL
          value: $(HOST):$(PORT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a single Pod spec, this works with exactly the syntax you described, but the environment variables must be defined (earlier) in the same Pod spec.  See [Define Dependent Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/) in the Kubernetes documentation.

```yaml
env:
  - name: HOST
    value: host.example.com
  - name: PORT
    value: '80'
  - name: URL
    value: '$(HOST):$(PORT)'
```

Beyond this, a Kubernetes YAML file needs to be totally standalone, and you can't use environment variables on the system running `kubectl` to affect the file content.  Other tooling like Helm fills this need better; see [@thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600600/10008173) for an example.

Comment: I'm guessing that this will work with environment variables that are already defined in the environment? We have a script with environment variables that gets generated as part of an initContainer. We're running `source /etc/our_script_of_secrets` as part of the commands that run for container startup

Comment: This only works for environment variables defined in the YAML itself.  An init container can't directly produce environment variables for the main process; you might need a Docker entrypoint script, or to use the native Kubernetes Secret mechanism, to get that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Helm with it's [variables](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/) seems like a better way of handling that kind use cases.
In the example below you have a deployment snippet with values and variables:

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "image/thomas:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: URL
              value: {{ .Values.host }}:{{ .Values.port }}
```

And here is one of the ways of deploying it with some custom variables:

```sh
helm upgrade --install  myChart . \
  --set image.tag=v2.5.4 \
  --set host=example.com \
  --set-string port=12345 \
```

Helm allows you also to use template functions. You can have `default`functions and this will go to default values if they're not filled. In the example above you can see `required` which display the message and fails to go further with installing the chart if you won't specify the value. There is also `include` function that allows you to bring in another template and pass results to other template functions.

Answer (score 1):

These manifests are complete files. Not a good way to use variables in it. Though you can.

use the below command to replace and pipe it to kubectl.

```
sed -i -e "s#%%HOST%%#http://whatever#" file.yml;
```

Though I would suggest to use [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#quickstart).

Read more:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/